# Why do "yes/no" values in Microsoft Access map to -1 and 0?

Tags: microsoft-access

The use of -1 puzzles me. I would have expected the values to be:

- NO --> 0
- YES --> +1

Is there an historical reason behind the use of -1 instead of +1?

Comment: -1, in twos-complement, is a number whose bits are all 1.

Comment: One of the reasons for this are because booleans within MS Access can also have no value or `Null` values.  As I thought the reason for it being -1 is because of the type of integer data type a boolean is defined as.  "This is because the Boolean data type is stored as a 16-bit signed integer."  The actual binary value of -1 is `1111111111111111`.  This question has been asked several times on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827447/why-is-yes-a-value-of-1-in-ms-access-database

Comment: @Ale - This also comes down to base 2 arithmetic. A bitwise NOT of anythng but `11111111 11111111` would not result in `00000000 00000000`.  The logical bitwise NOT of `False` should be `True` and vice versa.

Comment: @Ramhound Actually, `Yes/No` fields in Access cannot be `Null`, only `Yes/True` or `No/False`. If you try to force a `Yes/No` field to `Null` it simply becomes `No/False`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As discussed on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8827447/2144390), `Yes/True` values appear in Access as -1 because

- `Yes/No` fields in Access mimic `bit` fields,
- `Integer` values in Access are signed, [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) values,
- `No/False` is represented by 0, and
- the only other two's complement value of a 1-bit number is -1. To illustrate, two's complement numbers can have the following values:

3-bit:

```
bits  integer
----  -------
000         0
001         1
010         2
011         3
100        -4
101        -3
110        -2
111        -1
```

2-bit:

```
bits  integer
----  -------
00          0
01          1
10         -2
11         -1
```

1-bit:

```
bits  integer
----  -------
0           0
1          -1
```

For the integer representation of a `bit` field (i.e., 1-bit), if 0 is `No/False` then the only other value available for `Yes/True` is -1.